# Как сохранить значения для каждого if

Tags: c++

У меня есть переменная id, мне нужно сохранить ее значения и в тоже время выполнять условия.

Дело в том что мне нельзя использовать еще один цикл, но при этом я хочу проверить каждый if как будто они получили одинаковое значение id

```
int id = 2,
     a = 0;

for (;;) {
   switch (a) {
     case 1:
     {
        if (id != 0) // вначале должно выполнится это условия полностью
        {
           ServSock[id]; 
           id--;
           continue;
        }
        break;
     }
     case 2:
     {
        if (id != 0) // теперь это, но к сожалению id уже равен 0 это БЕДА!
        {
           ServSock[id]; 
           id--;
           continue;
        }
     }
     break;
   }
 a++; 
}
```

Пытался чет с двумя переменными сделать, но тогда ServSock[id] будет с разными переменными типа ServSock[id2], ServSock[id3] и это ужасно.

Что я пытаюсь сделать

я хочу сделать вот это

```
for (;;)
{
 for (i = 0; i < id; i++)
 {

     ServSock[i];
 }
 for (i = 0; i < id; i++)
 {

     ServSock[i];
 }
}
```

Только без двух лишних циклов внутри цикла и мне нужно что бы  ServSock[i]; был таким  ServSock[id];

Comment: Посвятите, пожалуйста, в задачу, выполняемую Вашим кодом. Два одинаковых условия и одиноко стоящий `ServSock[id];` вводят меня в заблуждение

Comment: Секунду я не дописал, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Лучше опишите словами, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Ваш код смысла не имеет.

Comment: Обновил, надеюсь понятно будет.

Comment: Чем пугает лишний цикл?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Неудобно читать когда кода много

Comment: Так разбейте код на подпрограммы. Явный цикл читать проще, чем костыли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
i = 0;
for (;;) {
  i--;
  if (i < 0)
    i = id - 1;
  ServSock[i];
}
```

В свете

> Неудобно читать когда кода много

Предлагаю написать так

```
void doLoop(int id) {
  for (int i = 0; i < id; i++) {
     ServSock[i];
  }
}

for (;;) {
  doLoop(id);
  doLoop(id);
}
```

Comment: Чет я запутался как это работает, можно с двумя условиями if?

Comment: @loli вот и я говорю, что циклы читабельнее костылей. Какие два `if` вам нужны?

Comment: Да походу так, но вдруг можно найти норм костыль который читабельней цикла будет :)

Comment: @loli если код функции не помещается в экран он уже нечитабельный

Comment: У меня там кода на две страницы, эта одна функция все :)
Я конечно легко могу все разобрать на функции но лучше от этого не станет.

Comment: @loli нечитабильный код - это когда в корпорации ПО разрабатывается более 10 лет, и он весь состоит из костылей, что даже документация не поможет разобраться.

Comment: @loli вот я и говорю - разбейте ее на подфункции

Comment: @loli, очень советую прочитать книгу «Совершенный код». Одна из немногих полезных книг по IT. И станет действительно гораздо лучше, если вы разберете код на функции. В книге вопросу функций посвящена отдельная глава.

Comment: @biggiemot Я сейчас поддерживаю 20-летний проект. И все читается

Comment: Если я разобью на подфункции я не смогу его оптимизировать.

Comment: @loli, да ну господи, забудьте вы про свои «оптимизации».

Comment: @loli Это как? Вообще связи не вижу

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вам повезло :) не будем переписку из этого делать.

Comment: @eanmos Книгу почитаю, эта она? https://fktpm.ru/file/84-sovershennyj-kod.pdf

Comment: @loli, нет, я ошибся в названии, должно быть «Чистый код» автор — Роберт Мартин. «Совершенный код» тоже полезная книга, но она гораздо более тяжелая. Начинайте с «Чистого кода».

Comment: @eanmos оно? http://menuteca.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/martin-chistyj-kod.2010.pdf

Comment: @loli, да, оно.